# Edit suggestion doesn't show the diff when code formatting is involved

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

Take a look at [one recently approved edit](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1821): there is no difference between original and edited question!

Suggestion was to apply code formatting, so the difference would be easy to spot and approve. Instead one needs to actually click through and view the original question.

Comment: Check the markdown differences. I suspect that the edits are formatting only.

Comment: @Chris: well the link is there, it's quite obvious that markdown diff is pretty useless as well.

Comment: Another example: [imgurl, duh](http://i.imgur.com/pyLcV.png)

Comment: Thanks so much for reporting this... it is a cluster of bugs ... 3 in fact

Answer (score 1):

This is actually 3 bugs:

1. The html diff was not working properly for side by side with code formatting
2. Markdown diff was not displaying leading and trailing spaces properly
3. LCS (the algorithm we use) has an edge case dealing with adding large chunks of enters at the end (not fixed yet)